# Problems connecting with Teradata database using pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

Currently, I'm running a simple python script to connect to a database:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=(MYDB);UID=(MYUSER); PWD=(MYPASS);QUIETMODE=YES')
```

With the server and credentials substituted in obviously. However, when running this script, I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('200', '[200] [unixODBC][eaaa[DCTrdt rvr o nuhifraint o n (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

The only help I've been able to find is [here](http://cjgoldsmith.blogspot.com/2011/03/teradata-odbc-python-pyodbc-on-fedora.html%20I%27ve) installed the **Teradata ODBC drivers**, but I just don't understand why I can't connect. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like following to connect:

```
TDCONN = pyodbc.connect('DSN=yourDSNname;',ansi=True, autocommit=True)
```

You can replace `DSN=yourDSNname;` with what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this "non english" error message problem. I think it was due to the wrong versions of libodbc.so and libodbcinst.so being used. Changing the links in /usr/lib/... to point to the teradata installed versions worked for me. Commands using the default install directories in Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit were:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ls -lha | grep odbc (To should see the files below which are to be replaced).
sudo mv libodbc.so.1.0.0 Xlibodbc.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/libodbc.so libodbc.so.1.0.0 
sudo mv libodbcinst.so.1.0.0 Xlibodbcinst.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/libodbcinst.so libodbcinst.so.1.0.0
```

I had also previously installed (through apt-get) odbcinst, so I redirected both files. But possibly only the first is needed.